# Using 'Contains' in linq query

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core, contains

Consider the below query:

```
  public async Task<IEnumerable<string>> GetItemNo(string itemNumber)
    {
        return await itemDbContext.Item
                     .Where(p => p.ItemNo.Contains(itemNumber)) 
                     .Select(p => p.ItemNo).ToListAsync();

    }
```

Instead of checking passed in characters exist in the same order (Which is how '.Contains' works right now).

How do I return list of ItemNos (string), even if few characters match and even if characters match in different place.

For eg:  If I pass in "appl" or "apole" or "dpple". I want DB to list "apple". Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use a metric that tells you if your string match is "good enough". One such metric is the [Levenshtein distance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Levenshtein_distance). You can calculate the distances between the input string and all the strings in your collection and then select those entries from the collection which have a distance that is low enough.

Comment: Great answer. Levenshtein distance helped solve the issue.

Answer (score 0):

You could write a function that compares those two strings `bool IsMatch(string a, string b);` and use it in the `Where` query

```
.Where(p => IsMatch(p.ItemNo, itemNumber) == true)
```